# Scheme - running through flat list of many types and adding strings

Tags: list, scheme, racket

Hey so I have to run through this list

```
(define disk
  '("D"
    "main"
    (("F" "file1.txt"
      (30)
      ("D" "sub1"
       (("F" "file1.txt" (1234))
        ("F" "file2.txt" (2345))
        ("F" "file3.txt" (3456))))
      ("D" "sub2"
       (("F" "file1.txt" (1234))
        ("F" "file2.txt" (2345))
        ("F" "file3.txt" (3456))))))))
```

This function will break the tree down into one flat list:

```
(define (visit-tree tree)
  (if (list? tree)
    (for-each visit-tree tree)
    (begin
      (display tree)
      (newline))))


 (visit-tree disk)
```

However, when I try to run through the code with my sum function, I get an error.

```
(let((sum 0))
   (visit-tree(lambda (x)
                (if (integer? x)
                    (set! sum (+ sum x))))
              disk)
   (display sum))

 visit-tree: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 1
  given: 2
  arguments...:
```

This is because my visit-tree function expects 2 args, but when I add in 'fn' as the second arg I just get another error.

```
(define (visit-tree fn tree)
  (if (list? tree)
    (for-each visit-tree fn tree)
    (begin
      (display tree)
      (newline))))


 (visit-tree fn disk)

 (let((sum 0))
   (visit-tree(lambda (x)
                (if (integer? x)
                    (set! sum (+ sum x))))
              disk)
   (display sum))
```

It tells me that fn has not been declared, which I understand, but how can I call in a lambda? How can I fix this code? Thank you.

Comment: what output are you expecting ?

Answer (score -1):

that was all i got..

```
(define(processElement a)
   (if (eq?(car a) "F")
     (file a)

  (display +(file a) (directory a)
  (if (eq?(car a) "D")

  (display +(file a) (directory a))))))


(define (file a)
  (display (car(cdr(cdr a)))))


(define (directory a)
(cdr a))


(define (processDirectoryContents a)
(if (null? a)
  (display "Finish")
(processElement a)
(processDirectoryContents a)
))


(directory disk)
```